# Does apache jenkins on Linux require an http server also?

Tags: windows, linux, http, jenkins

Getting started with Apache Jenkins. 
 Looking at the windows version of Apache Jenkins, as it installs, it seems to run on a particular web page over port 8080. Does it include an http server as part of that install too?

Is the same true for the Linux install?

Also, some of the related questions around the use of Jenkins mention http server - what's the particular reasons for installing a separate http server - is for security/authentication/control?

Thanks

Comment: This question is more suited to superuser.

Comment: I'm a technical lead / senior developer tasked with setting up an environment. Once I know my environment I'll develop hence the question on here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It comes with a bultin server but that's not really designed for production traffic. If your server is public facing, it's probably a good idea to treat it as an app server and put a real http server in front that proxies this.

Comment: Thanks for the good reply - appreciate it & makes sense.

Comment: It's only really for our development team use - i.e. to control Jenkins, and not for production use. What's the general guidance on this?

Comment: I think you can just expose the app server itself.